# Wordpress Automatic Plugin Update Renames Plugin Directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

So I have hooked the wordpress plugin auto updated to effectively redirect my plugin to autoupdate from my own site rather than wordpress.com.

The updating process works seemlessly aside from one wierd hitch - the wordpress updater downloads the `my_plugin.zip` file from my server, saves it in a temp directory as `my_plugin-3sd123.tmp` (where the random string is generated by the wp updater to avoid file conflicts) and unzips it to `wp-content/upgrades` which leaves a directory `my_plugin-3sd123` in updates and then it copies this directory to `plugins` and removes the old directory BUT never renames the new one to the old plugin slug.. 
Should I be writing my plugins to expect this? because I dont see it happening with other plugin updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer was simple I didnt have my plugins content in a subdirectory slug inside the zip file
eg.
I had :

```
my_plugin.zip
   |- my_plugin.php
   |- admin
        |-admin.php
```

I should have had

```
my_plugin.zip
   |-my_plugin
        |-my-plugin.php
        |-admin
            |-admin.php
```

Once you add that sub directory the auto updated will work as expected

Comment: I have the same plugin structure like your second example, but the folder still gets renamed with a random string somehow. Any idea what else can cause this?